# List of all domain classes in Grails

Tags: list, grails, dns, partial-classes

how can I get a list of alle domain classes I use in my project? Something like `GORM.domains.list()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using

```
grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")
```

you get a list of [GrailsDomainClass](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.html) instances that hold meta-information regarding the domain class. The domain class itself is returned by Calling getClazz(). In short:

```
grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")*.clazz
```

returns a complete list of the existing domain classes.

Comment: Newer grails versions also support grailsApplication.domainClasses as well as getArtefacts.