# How can I print the available tables and databases?

Tags: grails, groovy

is there any good way (or any way at all) to list all the available tables and databases with Grails? Imagine a project where the database is optional and it's up to the user to select which database / table to use.

I would like a way to list the available databases and tables for the current user. Preferably I would like this done with GORM for obvious reasons but I can't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a domain class for database names , show it to the user and according to the selected database , create respective datasource and fire the sql queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how to list tables.

If you already have domain classes for those tables, you can just list them like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707796/list-of-all-domain-classes-in-grails), then [get the related table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664845/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-table-gorm-object-is-mapped-to).

Otherwise you'll need a native sql query, which, I suppose, will be DB vendor-specific.

Comment: Okay, this is a problem though. Since I don't know the table names I can't have domain classes for them. I was afraid for that native SQL query. Maybe Grails ain't the job for this project.

Comment: @cubsink, for this problem grails won't help you. Even if you select your tables via a native query (e.g. using groovy.sql.Sql), you will continue working with them again via native sql because you don't have related domains. No domains - no GORM.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm gonna look at other languages then. This should be able to do with python and flask. :)