# How do I proxy a production database with a testing database?

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm

I'm currently working on a Grails project which has a static production database with a lot of data in it.  I would like to test my application using the production data, but instead of having to clone the production database I'd like to setup a proxy database to the production database.

Essentially reads of the database would go all the way to production database while writes would stop at a proxy database (preferably an h2 database).  If a row was updated that came from the production database the row would be saved to the proxy database and returned, instead of the production's row, on subsequent queries.

I'd like to do all of this as transparently to the application as possible.  My currently line of thinking is that I'd need to fork the Hibernate GORM implementation and make it support this use case.  Has this been done before?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forking the Hibernate `GORM` implementation may not be a good idea. You will be stuck in your version and will have to, somehow, make this up to date with the original plugin (eg. bug fix, new implementations).

Maybe a custom [TestMixin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/TestMixin.html) that allows you to override [all registered domain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707796/list-of-all-domain-classes-in-grails), with new implementations of `save()`, `get()`, `find()` and etc can be an option. You can work with the [metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses) to override this static methods and this will be triggered only on tests with the annotated mixin.

With this you can use multiple datasources in the test environment to determine which will be used.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but it limits my usage only to automated testing.  I'd really like this to work with run-app as well.

Comment: You mean that you want this behavior for both dev and integration envs?

Comment: The first goal would actually be to get this working on the development environment (at least that is where my heads at).  The integration environment presents it's own set of challenges since the database might not be in a known state.

Comment: In the case of development, you can wrap your logic in a Spring Bean, and call this on Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're saying.  What logic are you thinking I should wrap in the Spring Bean?

Comment: Istead of having a TestMixin that overrides save(), get() and etc, create a Spring Bean or a utility class. Then you can call this on the mixin and on bootstrap if the env is development.

Comment: Last question:  While overriding the save and get methods seems pretty trivial overriding all the finds is eluding me.  Do you have any thoughts on overloading all the dynamic finders for a domain class?

Comment: Maybe with invokeMethod? http://blog.art-of-coding.eu/method-interception-and-synthesis-with-groovy/